# Wordpress Loop for bootstrap carousel

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I was trying to display more than 5 items at once on a single slide, which by default suppose to be just one. I tried creating two loops, one to place content inside the active class and another to place content inside the item class, with post_per_page = 3, what I am getting a first output post three posts on the home, but after first slide it changes to one, what's the possible solution towards this.

Thanks in advance.

I hope you understand, that was my best way to explain this.

Here is what I want to achieve[image: here is what i want to achieve].

Here is my code

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
 <!-- Carousel items -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
 <?php 
  $my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>
   <!-- The 1st Loop... -->
   <div class="active item well-blue">
     <div class="offset1">              
     <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
     <p class="lead"><?php $excerpt = strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); echo $excerpt; ?></p>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read more...</a>
   </div> 
 </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?> <?php
      // The 2nd Loop limits the query to 2 more posts...
    $limit_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3');
  while ($limit_query->have_posts()) :$limit_query->the_post();$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>
<!-- The 2nd Loop same data as 1st loop -->
<div class="item well-blue">
     <div class="offset1">              
     <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
     <p class="lead"><?php $excerpt = strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); echo $excerpt; ?></p>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read more...</a>
   </div> 
 </div>
<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this link : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/bootstrap-carousel-and-wordpress-loop-without-postspages

you just need to find this line

```
// Item size (set here the number of posts for each group)
$i = 4;
```

And change 4 to 5.